# Is it possible to make this addons?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I am still learning programming (PHP for now) and HTML. I want to learn how to make a firefox add ons, but I am not really sure how. What programming language do I need to use or what software?
If I could make one, I want to make an customizable icon/logo to my fav website, for example I can put an facebook icon/logo right next to my homepage icon, but I can change it (or add if it possible) to any website and can change the logo picture and the link. is that possible?

P.S. Sorry bad English and I hate bookmarks toolbar :(

Comment: javascript. yes its very easy. http://www.bing.com/search?q=addon+sdk+mdn&pc=MOZI&form=MOZLBR